# How to mantain uniform alignment in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-percentrelativelayout

I'm trying to find a way to keep text views in a complex layout uniform aligned. Is there a way to position the "1B" `TextView` directly under the "1A" `TextView` and above the "1C" `TextView` whilst avoiding too much nesting?

NB: The "1B" & "1C" `TextViews` are in a `RelativeLayout` together as part of an expandable `RecyclerView`

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutA">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutA">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ibA"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvA"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ibA"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutB">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvB"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ivC"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvB"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvC"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvB"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivC"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="A 1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `textView2`, `textView3` & `imageView4` need to be in some layout for expanding and hiding in Recyclerview